# CakePHP 3.x Sidebar is not showing any content

Tags: cakephp, sidebar, cakephp-3.x

I was trying create a left side menu bar.  I used the following code in my layout file `Templates/Layout/admin.ctp`

```
    // Create the sidebar block.
    $this->start('sidebar');
    echo $this->fetch('sidebar');
    echo $this->element('sidebar/left_menu');
    $this->end();
```

But the sidebar is not showing in the page.  The Left menu sidebar file is located at `Templates/Element/Sidebar/left_menu.ctp`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the formatting of your question - as of now it is difficult to read it. It is also best to avoid `Thanks in advance! Babitha` as it doesn't add any useful information, only adds noise.

Comment: Where is your `<?=$this->fetch('sidebar') ?>`?

Comment: I have edited the question.
@Inigo Flores I have added it in my script. Still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things I can point out:

- The default directory for templates is **src/Template** and not Templates
- As you are starting the block, *fetch('sidebar')* will return empty. Try putting it after the end of the block

  ```
  // Create the sidebar block
  $this->start('sidebar');
  echo $this->element('sidebar/left_menu');
  $this->end();

  // Display the sidebar
  $this->fetch('sidebar');
  ```

Comment: Hey Its working. Thank you Douglas. 'Templates' was a typo. I tried putting $this->fetch('sidebar'); in the end of the block.